# What does cv::TermCriteria() exactly do in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

[Official documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-rc1/d9/d5d/classcv_1_1TermCriteria.html#a56fecdc291ccaba8aad27d67ccf72c57) said that `TermCriteria(int Type, int MaxCount, double epsilon)` is for defining termination criteria for iterative algorithms. And criteria type can be one of: `COUNT`, `EPS` or `COUNT + EPS`.

However, I can't quite understand what SVM does different in each iteration when I use `svm->setTermCriteria(const cv::TermCriteria & val)`.

Answer (score 0):

SVM training can be considered a large-scale quadratic programming problem and unfortunately it cannot be easily solved with standartd QP techniques. That's why in the past several years numerous decomposition algorithms were introduced in the literature.

The basic idea of these algorithms is to decompose the large QP problem into a series of smaller QP sub-problems. That is, in each iteration the algorithm keeps fixed most dimension of the optimization variable vector and varies a small subset of dimensions (namely working set) to get maximumal reduction of the object function.

As far as I know, OpenCV uses the [SVMlight](http://svmlight.joachims.org/) or generalized [SMO](http://www.keerthis.com/) algorithm and the `TermCriteria` parameter is a termination criteria of the iterative SVM training procedure which solves the above mentioned partial case of constrained QP problem. You can specify tolerance and/or the maximum number of iterations.